# How to share data between devices using firestore?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I would like to share data between two users in my app. Generally, users are registered in the app and the storage of their data is done via Firestore. To access the data I use the UID of the user on the one hand and an id for the corresponding document inside a collection to be accessed on the other.

I am now looking for a way to share some selected data of a user with other users. The data is to be shared via WhatsApp, Email, etc., for example. These are the ways I have thought of so far:

1. The DataClass with all the stored data is packaged as an app-specific file and sent between the users.

**or**

2. The UID of the user and the id of the corresponding document inside the collection are sent. Using these two pieces of information, I can access the data from the user who is to receive the data via Firestore and save it on his or her device.

In general, my data sets are not particularly large. Now to my question:

Which of the two ways seems to make more sense and, above all, how can I implement this or which other sites could help me?
I've tried a few things with FileProvider so far, but haven't really got anywhere. It would be important that the user in question receives a message via e.g. WhatsApp, email, etc., can open my app via this, and the processing of the data for the user begins. Basically, I need to start an intent from the message the user receives with some extra data. How can I achieve that?

If you need any further information, please just let me know. Many thanks in advance!

Comment: To understand better, you need to send (share) a file between two users?

Comment: Yes, exactly. A user creates a file and should be able to share it with others who have installed my app. The data itself is only relevant within my app and structured as a document from a data class within Firestore.

Comment: Then why not use [Cloud Storage for Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage)?

Comment: Well, as I mentioned before, the data is really small, so I don't think it's necessary to manage it with a storage solution. I have looked at Cloud Storage but it doesn't really seem to fit my needs. The question is, how can I package my data as an app specific file and share it between users **or** how can I send the information to another user whose data in Firestore can be accessed by another user via the IDs provided. Do you also think that Firebase Dynamic Links would fit my needs or do you know another way to get to a solution?

Comment: Yes, you should give it a try and use Firebase Dynamic Links.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to have a look at [Firebase Dynamic Links](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links), which:

> If a user opens a Dynamic Link on iOS or Android, they can be taken directly to the linked content in your native app.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Seems promissing to me.

Comment: Thank you, I have already implemented Firebase Dynamic Links in my app and it works as intended. Best regards, Markus

Comment: Good to hear this worked for you Markus! 